# MVC 3 (Razor) - Standard way to use a Button event to call Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a simple Wall.cshtml view that loads a _Search.cshtml **Partial View** that looks like this:

```
<h2>The Wall</h2>
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Search/_Search.cshtml");}
```

The _Search.cshtml Partial View (updated based on @Darin reply) looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Searching", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "searchForm" }))    
{  
    <div id="search">
        <div id="searchbtn">
           <input id="Search" type="button" value="Search" />
        </div>
        <div id="searchtxt">
           @Html.TextBox("txtSearch")
        </div>
  </div>
}
```

The Controller looks like this:

```
public class SearchController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Wall()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Searching()
    {
        // do something with the search value
        return View();
    }
}
```

When I run the app, the resulting block of HTML produced looks like this:

```
<form action="/Search/Searching" id="searchForm" method="post">  
   <div id="search">
      <div id="searchbtn">
          <input id="Search" type="button" value="Search" />
      </div>
      <div id="searchtxt">
          <input id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" type="text" value="" />
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

**QUESTION 1:**  Why would the button click never hit the **Searching Controller** method?
(let me restate that _Search.cshtml is a Partial view that runs inside a view named Wall.cshtml).

**QUESTION 2:**  How would I get the value inside the "txtSearch" textbox?

**QUESTION 3:**  Since this is a Partial View, how do I make the view that holds the current Search Partial View ..to refresh and update itself with the result of the Search query?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It would be better to use a form and making the search button submit:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "searchForm" }))    
{
    <div id="search">
        <div id="searchbtn">
            <input id="Search" type="submit" value="Search" />
        </div>
        <div id="searchtxt">
            @Html.TextBox("txtSearch")
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

As far as your second question is concerned, you could AJAXify this search form:

```
$(function() {
    $('#searchForm').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            success: function(result) {
                $('#resultContainer').html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

where `resultContainer` could be some div that will harbor the search results returned from the controller action.

Comment: Solution1 was something i did before but as stated on the updated original reply, the button click never reaches the Searching Controller method.

Comment: @Filu, and what happens when you inspect the request in FireBug? What is the reason for not reaching the controller?

Comment: I must admit, i never used Firebug. I just installed it. What shall i be looking for when I click on the button?

Comment: @Filu, look at the console tab. It will show you AJAX requests, javascript errors, etc...

Comment: ...it's always like that. I woke up this night and thought, what "type" is the button?  ...it's a "button" instead of "input".

That was the problem :--)

Answer (score 2):

the problem was that the `<input id="Search" type="button" value="Search" />`
has a type  = **BUTTON**

I changed the Type to be **INPUT** ...and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to serialize the data to push also the Model to the Controller Action:

```
@model CBS.DataAccess.Entities.SupplierQuoteEntity     
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "SupplierQuote", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SupplierQuoteCreateForm" }))
{ 
    <div>blablablabla fields...</div>

    <a class="t-button t-button-icontext" onclick="ajaxSubmit()"><span class="t-icon t-insert"></span>Create</a>  

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ajaxSubmit() {
            var formData = $("#SupplierQuoteCreateForm").serializeArray();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Create", "SupplierQuote")',
                data: formData,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }        
    </script>    
}
```